# Disable Android Beam for selected activities

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I'm working with NFC on Android, specifically with Android Beam. My question is: is it possible to disable Android Beam support for an activity?

This is what some system applications do, such as messaging: if another phone is put close, my phone vibrates but the "Touch to beam" screen doesn't appear and the other phone doesn't receive anything.

EDIT: Calling:

```
NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(NdefMessage message, Activity activity, Activity... activities)
```

in `onResume()` with a `null` message should do the trick (the doc says: "Pass a null NDEF message to disable foreground NDEF push in the specified activities.") but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: wait so basically its not working for you, you don't actually want to disable it. are both phones enable for android beam? its a setting on the phone?

Comment: Beam is perfectly working, but I want to disable message sending for some activities in my app. Right now it is enabled for every activity.

Comment: that sounds more like your own implementation issue than an api issue. how are you sending data between nfc and your activities?

Answer (score 5):

When I do it like this, It works like a charm.

```
NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this); 
adapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this currently. Maybe you can provide a menu option to disable NFC in your app? Why do you want to do this, by the way?

EDIT:

Sorry, there is a way to do this. Call setNdefPushMessage() in the activities that you don't want to push anything with a null NDEF message. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Because most of the activities in my app don't have anything meaningful to send, and if I try sending from them, my app is started on the other phone, and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: I edited my question too pointing to the same method, but that didn't work :(